# Nginx shows correct rewrite data, but not executing as expected

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have a laravel app running behind Nginx using fastcgi.
There are images available at [www.example.com/media/images/someImage.jpeg](http://www.example.com/media/images/someImage.jpeg)

There are also images of different size of the same image available at [www.example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg](http://www.example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg)

There is a script running on laravel which makes this image available for this size IF its not existing available at [www.example.com/api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg](http://www.example.com/api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg)

For example if [www.example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg](http://www.example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg) does not exist, [www.example.com/api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg](http://www.example.com/api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg) can be accessed which will show the image and now this image also exists under [www.example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg](http://www.example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg), hopefully this makes sense.

Ok so the issue I am trying to figure out right now is how to make this happen with nginx rewrite.

Idea is that when user tries to access www. example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg and it does not exist, nginx rewrites this to /api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg (the script) and shows the generated image, but all of this without changing the URL. So the URL requested stays like www. example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg but under the hood it requests the script at /api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg and shows the generated image at the same www. example.com/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg.

My nginx config is as below

```
server {
    listen  8080;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;       #this is for rancher purposes
    set $target app-fpm.app.svc.cluster.local;             #also this

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location /media/images/ {
        alias /var/www/storage/app/public/media/images/;
        try_files $uri /$uri @generator;
    }
    location @generator {
        rewrite ^/media/images/(.*)  /api/images/$1 last;
    }
    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass $target:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I have enabled rewrite debug in nginx and in error log I can see this -

```
2020/09/11 23:14:28 [notice] 1034#1034: *161 "^/media/images/(.*)" matches "/media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg", client: 10.42.0.0, server: , request: "GET /media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "www. example .com"
2020/09/11 23:14:28 [notice] 1034#1034: *161 rewritten data: "/api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg", args: "", client: 10.42.0.0, server: , request: "GET /media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "www. example .com"
```

As you can see rewritten data is correct, it is /api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg, but it shows 404 error as per access.log

```
10.42.0.0 - - [11/Sep/2020:23:33:43 +0300] "GET /media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 622 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
```

But it should show the new generated image instead.
Is this even possible what I am trying to achieve here?

I would really appreciate the help,
Thank you!

Comment: Is this config complete? If you also had a `location ~ \.jpg$ {` somewhere, then it would match that and subsequently not "go through" the PHP generation.

Comment: In that case what I should add to location ~ \.jpg$ {} block? Fastcgi? Thing is I can open .jpg files just fine, and when accessing /api/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg directly from browser, it opens generated image (script works) but it does not do anything when accessing /media/images/660x440/someImage.jpeg